# Codigo visible en netlify

Tags: reactjs, deployment

He publicado mi pagina web en netlify, la construi usando ReactJS, pero al ver las fuentes en el inspector de codigo puedo ver todo mi codigo fuente, como puedo prevenir eso?
Gracias.

Comment: así funciona eso (creo), no puedes prevenir eso

Comment: a que te referis con el codigo fuente??? que tipo de codigo ves?'?? el js????

Comment: asi es,puedo ver el codigo que tengo tal cual lo tengo en mis componentes

Comment: mira, te dejo este articulo. tal vez te ayude [enlace](https://www.yoseomarketing.com/blog/ocultar-codigo-fuente-html-de-una-web-como/#:~:text=de%20tu%20p%C3%A1gina.-,Cifrar%20la%20p%C3%A1gina,le%20permita%20al%20navegador%20descifrarlo.&text=Un%20usuario%20es%20capaz%20de,sin%20embargo%2C%20no%20es%20comprensible.)

Comment: prueba a poner: GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false en el archivo .env, esto hará que no genere el source map, que es lo que permite al navegador reconstruir el código original a partir del compilado